# Understanding grep within Enumerable module

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, enumerable

I greatly appreciate any assistance on my first stack-overflow post!

I was generally confused why I am receiving and empty array every time I try to run my code.
*I am creating a method that will filter for a gender of "M" and return its elements.*

I am sure there are a multitude of ways to successfully run this code but I was interested in using grep and its functionality. It being a shortcut and all I thought it would be good to learn. Thank you once again.

```
students = [
    {name: 'John', grade: 8, gender: 'M'},
    {name: 'Sarah', grade: 12, gender: 'F'},
    {name: 'Bob', grade: 16, gender: 'M'},
    {name: 'Johnny', grade: 2, gender: 'M'},
    {name: 'Ethan', grade: 4, gender: 'M'},
    {name: 'Paula', grade: 8, gender: 'F'},
    {name: 'Donald', grade: 5, gender: 'M'},
    {name: 'Jennifer', grade: 13, gender: 'F'},
    {name: 'Courtney', grade: 15, gender: 'F'},
    {name: 'Jane', grade: 9, gender: 'F'}
]
```

```
def is_male(gender)
  gender.grep(/M/) { |gend| gend[:gender] }
end
p is_male(students)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [docs of `Enumerable#grep`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Enumerable.html#method-i-grep):

> ```
> grep(pattern) → array
> grep(pattern) { |obj| block } → array
> ```
>
> Returns an array of every element in `enum` for which `Pattern === element`. If the optional block is supplied, each matching element is passed to it, and the block’s result is stored in the output array.

The important part is this method returns elements that evaluate `Pattern === element` to `true`. But `/M/ === {name: 'John', grade: 8, gender: 'M'}` does not return `true`, same for all other elements in your array.

Therefore your result set is empty in the first place.

The block – `{ |gend| gend[:gender] }` in your example – is only evaluated when and after there was a pattern match. The block changes the return value of the whole call but not how the pattern matching is done.

Please note the docs for [`Rexgxp#===`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Regexp.html#method-i-3D-3D-3D) in this context too.

Answer (score 0):

> I am creating a method that will filter for a gender of "M" and return its elements.

With the above requirements in mind, your naming seems quite misleading:

```
def is_male(gender)
  # ...
end
```

The above looks like a method that takes a gender and checks whether it is male. I'd expect something like this:

```
is_male('M') #=> true
is_male('F') #=> false
```

And `is_male(students)` isn't clear either – does it check whether there is a male student in the given array? Or if all of the students are male? Either way, it doesn't sound like filtering.

---

Let's start by renaming the method and its argument to match your requirements more closely:

```
def male_students(students)
  # ....
end
```

If you want to use `grep` you have to provide a *pattern* which is an object responding to `===`. A regular expression won't work, because it operates on strings and our students are hashes (more on that below). You *could* use a [`Proc`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.0.0/Proc.html) instead which also responds to `===`:

```
def male_students(students)
  is_male = ->(student) { student[:gender] == 'M' }
  students.grep(is_male)
end
```

But it's easier to use [`select`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.0.0/Array.html#select-method):

```
def male_students(students)
  students.select { |student| student[:gender] == 'M' }
end
```

---

Another option is to use a custom class for your students because right now, your students are merely hashes:

```
class Student
  attr_accessor :name, :grade, :gender

  def initialize(name:, grade:, gender:)
    @name = name
    @grade = grade
    @gender = gender
  end

  def male?
    gender == 'M'
  end

  def female?
    gender == 'F'
  end
end
```

Now, change your array accordingly:

```
students = [
  Student.new(name: 'John', grade: 8, gender: 'M'),
  Student.new(name: 'Sarah', grade: 12, gender: 'F'),
  Student.new(name: 'Bob', grade: 16, gender: 'M'),
  Student.new(name: 'Johnny', grade: 2, gender: 'M'),
  Student.new(name: 'Ethan', grade: 4, gender: 'M'),
  Student.new(name: 'Paula', grade: 8, gender: 'F'),
  Student.new(name: 'Donald', grade: 5, gender: 'M'),
  Student.new(name: 'Jennifer', grade: 13, gender: 'F'),
  Student.new(name: 'Courtney', grade: 15, gender: 'F'),
  Student.new(name: 'Jane', grade: 9, gender: 'F'),
]
```

And you can use this pretty minimal syntax:

```
students.select(&:male?)
#=>
# [
#   #<Student:0x00007fb18d826ce8 @name="John", @grade=8, @gender="M">,
#   #<Student:0x00007fb18d826b58 @name="Bob", @grade=16, @gender="M">,
#   #<Student:0x00007fb18d826a90 @name="Johnny", @grade=2, @gender="M">,
#   #<Student:0x00007fb18d8269c8 @name="Ethan", @grade=4, @gender="M">,
#   #<Student:0x00007fb18d826838 @name="Donald", @grade=5, @gender="M">
#  ]
```

Or any of the other useful methods in `Array` / `Enumerable`:

```
students.any?(&:male?)  #=> true
students.all?(&:male?)  #=> false
students.count(&:male?) #=> 5
```